# Install packages from the Debian Snapshot Archives repo?

Tags: linux, debian, docker, apt-get

The [Debian Snapshot Archive](http://snapshot.debian.org/) describes being able to add the snapshot repositories into `/etc/apt/sources.list` so that one can install debian binaries using `apt-get` directly from the archive.

This sounds straight-forward.  However, when I configure a vanilla Debian machine as described with `sources.list` pointing to the snapshot versions of the repos, `apt-get install` refuses to install the dependencies. For example, the call:

```
 apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends r-base
```

Results in the error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 2.11.1-6) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 2.11.1-6) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

`apt-cache show r-base-core` etc show the requested packages and versions exist, so it's not clear why it does not simply install them.

It is easy to illustrate this problem using a Dockerfile, [like this](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned/tree/master/binary/2.12.0-repo), in order to attempt installing debian packages on a vanilla Debian release from any computer running docker.

I note that installing from the snapshot archives works just fine if I grab the specific `.deb` files from the Snapshot Archive (e.g. [this dockerfile](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned/tree/master/binary/2.12.0/Dockerfile)), but clearly that is not the intended method outlined on the [Debian Snapshot Archive](http://snapshot.debian.org/) which says to just add the repos to `souces.list`.

Comment: If you expand it to the listed packages, ie here `apt-get install r-base r-base-core r-recommended` and keep going you eventually get to a real or apparent package conflict.  It is worth remembering that Debian makes releases, and strives to have everything consistent for the releases. Rolling releases ("testing") also work; randomly jumping to a point in time is harder -- so there can be conflicts.

Comment: thanks! so this issue is limited to the packages I've picked then.  If I add the repos from an (earlier) standard release to sources.list, always installs the older version from the standard release.  Even `apt-cache show` only shows the old version (after `apt-get update`ing), so it seems to be ignoring the snapshot repos?

Comment: Can you please update with the snapshot you are using? I.E. your sources.list. The Dockerfile snippet where you are doing this would be extremely helpful as well.

Comment: @Crackers `sources.list` is already linked (see 'using a Dockerfile, like this'), pointing to this page with the `sources.list` and `Dockerfile` Sorry it wasn't more clear. https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned/tree/master/binary/2.12.0-repo

Comment: it is ignoring the snapshot repo because of the debian name. I do not know why but if you use sid it will work: "deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20101017/ sid  main"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand exactly why it fails, but I found a work-around:

```
FROM debian:wheezy

### SNAPSHOTTING: create a new source + preferences for r-* deb pkgs
RUN echo \
  'deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20101017/ sid  main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/snapshot.list \
  && printf "Package: r-*\nPin: origin snapshot.debian.org\nPin-Priority: 990\n" > /etc/apt/preferences.d/snapshot \
  &&  apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update

# install recommended
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  --allow-unauthenticated r-base-dev
```

I will send a pull request

Comment: It never makes sense to ignore signature validation (`--allow-unauthenticated`), especially since it is the only defense against man-in-the-middle and tampering with the server.